# Is there any way for adding non-form elements to GET URL?

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I need to pass some data over GET URL which is not in form, is there any way to include non-form data into GET method?

```
http://localhost/land1/index.php?visitorName=&visitorPhone=&submit=Submit
```

which is ok for form elements like visitorName and visitorPhone, but i need to pass some other info also with this, like some fixed non-form data.

And i have to use only html, in form submitting page, no php.., target is php.

Comment: Can you use javascript? It is possible with that!

Comment: **YES**, you can. Jquery / javascript with ajax helps you to send non-form data easily.

Comment: Get and post data belongs to form so you its not possible to send get data from submitting form. If you don't need to create a input field actually then you can append that data with url

Comment: Please elaborate. You already have a html form with some (named, valid) controls in it but on submit of _that_ form you want to transfer additional parameters? If yes: When and from where do those additional parameters come; what is providing this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use input `type=hidden` for this purpose.

For e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fixedData" value="some data" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that cleared a big headache. I am using this in HTML-email, nothing other than HTML is supported in that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax in this case-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400')
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/myUrl?<[parameters]>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

You can add form as well as non-form parameters here -

xmlhttp.open("GET", "/myUrl?<[parameters]>", true);